# How to iterate through dictionary to match key value to string value

Tags: python, roman-numerals

Im trying to solve roman numeral leetcode in python. here is my code

i tried multiple ways of comparing the dictionary to the key value and then each single character of the string to the dictionary but dont know how to put it in code.

```
class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        LETTERS = {"I": 1,"V":5,"X":10,"L":50,"C":100,"D":500,"M":1000}
        total = 0
        for key in LETTERS:
            if key == s[1:]:
                total += LETTERS[key]

        return total
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to iterate through your keys but through the string to get converted. First change your loop to something like:

```py
for symbol in s:
     total += LETTERS[symbol]
```

However there is an issue with roman numbers like IV being 4 and IX being 9 with such approach.

Comment: this isn't quite right; the string should be iterated over/consumed, but `"IV"` should be `4`, not `6`

Comment: Of course, this won't correctly calculate the actual value (i.e., "IV" and "VI" would both give 6 rather than 4 and 6), but this definitely is the solution to the OPs question.

Comment: you are both right, guys, would update that

Comment: You may be better using `enumerate` on the string,so you get the key and the index because in addition to problems with IV 4 and IX 9, you may also have to deal with XL 50, XC 90, and CM 900. So the index would allow you to check the string's following component and flip the increment negative, if need be.